# Attach debugger to Package Manager Console

Tags: powershell, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I forked a project that generates code using T4Scaffolding. The user generates a scaffold and template by executing a cmdlet in the Package Manager Console. I would like to attach a debugger to the Package Manager Console to step through an example, but I do not know the name of the process which runs the Powershell host inside the PMC.

Does anyone know how to attach a debugger to the Package Manager Console?

Comment: Which kind of app or code did you want to debug? You couldn't use the package manager console outside visual studio, it is just a PowerShell console within Visual Studio used to interact with NuGet and automate Visual Studio. It would not have a single process unless you want to attach to the VS process or the NuGeT.exe. So not very sure that what example you want to debug in your side, can you debug it directly in the VS editor?

Comment: I want to do the exact same thing. Did you ever have any luck getting debugging to work in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [NuGetDebugTools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGetDebugTools/).

> Simple and yet effective script debugging, tracing, coverage, and
>   other tools. They are designed for any PowerShell host and may be used in the NuGet console for debugging and testing NuGet and Visual Studio specific scripts.